# Code Does Not work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

when i open the window with `$window.open` using angular js .I pass the object `$popup.mapinfo` to another controller. Its working fine in all browser except IE.
can any one help me ??

```
$window.open('modules/map/views/myModalContent.html','','width=900,height=900');
$popup.mapInfo = divText;
//  console.log($popup.mapInfo);
//  var doc = myWindow.document;
//  doc.open();
//  doc.write(divText);
//  doc.close();
```

Comment: What version of IE? And Angular? And what is `$popup`?

Comment: IE 8, $popup.mapinfo does not pass in my second controller

Comment: IE8 support for Angular is limited to 1.2 and below so check your Angular version. If you need to use 1.3 ore greater and must support IE8 then check this https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds

Comment: still it does not work